# How to use MessageChannel in transactional context with Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ibm-mq, spring-cloud-stream

I am working on an application where I read from a IBM MQ queue, process the message, and then send that message to a Kafka Topic. I am trying to handle the case where my Kafka broker goes down. In that case, I want my application to rollback the transaction and try to write to the Kafka topic again for X number of retries after which I will send the message to a back up queue. However, i am having trouble throwing an exception on the messageChannel.send call. I am unable to make it timeout. The application is infinitely blocked on the messageChannel.send call. Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class MainQueueListener {

    @Value("${mq.queueName}")
    String queueName;
    private ExecutionFlow executionFlow;

    public MainQueueListener(final ExecutionFlow executionFlow ) {
        this.executionFlow= executionFlow;
    }

    /**
     * Receive message from main queue.
     * The containerFactory is defined in infrastructure.jms.JmsComfig
     * @param byteMessage JMSBytesMessage 
     */
    @JmsListener(containerFactory = "jmsFactory", destination = "${mq.queueName}")
    public void receiveMessage(JMSBytesMessage byteMessage) {
        executionFlow .execute(byteMessage, queueName);
    }
}
```

Configs for the transaction manager and listener container.

```
public class JmsConfig {

    private JmsErrorHandler errorHandler = new JmsErrorHandler();

    /**
     * Default JmsListenerContainer could be modified if needed
     * @param connectionFactory 
     */

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                     DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * Instanciating a JmsTransactionManager: a local transaction manager. It will receive the ConnectionFactory
     */
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
        jmsTransactionManager.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
        jmsTransactionManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
        return jmsTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

The execution flow will call the messageChannel.send :

```
 public void sendMessage(MessageTarget messageTarget) {

        MessageChannel messageChannel;
        String topicName = messageTarget.getDestination();
        switch (topicName) {
            case "A":
                messageChannel = MessageStreams.outboundMessageA();
                break;
            case "B":
                messageChannel = MessageStreams.outboundMessageB();
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid destination: " + topicName);
        }

            Message message = MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload(messageTarget.getResponse())
                    .build();
            System.out.println(messageChannel.send(message,3000)); //stuck here no timeout
    }
```

And finally my application config file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: txn.
            producer:
              sync: true
              configuration:
                acks: all
                enable:
                  idempotence: true
                retries: 10
                max:
                  block:
                    ms: 5000
      bindings:
        AResponseOutputStreamChannel:
          destination: topicA
        BResponseOutputStreamChannel:
          destination: topicB

  mustache:
    check-template-location: false


ibm:
  mq:
    queue-manager: QM1
    conn-name: localhost(1414)
    channel: DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN
    user: xxx
    password: xxx

mq.queueName: Q1
bo-queue: Q2
```

Here is the output when the listener receives a message and i kill my local kafka docker container before calling the messageChannel.send. None of the timeot in the send call or the max.block.ms parameter seems to make a difference.

```
2019-08-15 20:47:02,365 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:04,371 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:06,281 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:08,391 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:10,399 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:12,408 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:14,419 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:16,425 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:18,434 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:20,342 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:22,556 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:24,565 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:26,470 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:28,377 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:30,386 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:32,289 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:34,397 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:36,408 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-08-15 20:47:38,518 WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=txn.0] Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug; I see this...

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 5000milliseconds while awaiting EndTxn(COMMIT)
```

After the failure, we are attempting to close the producer, but we call the `close()` method with no timeout, so it hangs until the broker comes back up.